# Manually set global $post vars with an ID, in order to use template tags

Tags: plugins, posts, functions, loop, template-tags

I have a function retrieving ID's of posts by very specific means.

I need to be able to set the `global $post` in order to use functions like `the_content()`, which does not allow an ID as a parameter.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "set the global $post"? Could you please a) post the function retrieving the IDs and illustrate/sketch your use case?

Answer (score 42):

When your going through your loop add this:

```
global $post; 
$post = get_post( $ID, OBJECT );
setup_postdata( $post );

//Do something

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Answer (score 3):

To work with posts *outta loop*  try using:

`get_post(post_id)`

to get a post with a specific ID **out of the loop**,when you do this,the global object $post will hold the post which you'v just selected.Now you can get the content using :

`$post->post_content` .

check the [get_post documentation on Wordpress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post#Return)

Answer (score 1):

You may use a one-liner to reset the global post object.

```php
setup_postdata( $GLOBALS['post'] =& $custom_post_object );
```

When you finish your template or loop be sure to reset the global post so you won't break other templates further down the stack.

```php
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Note: [PHPCS](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress-Coding-Standards) with WordPress standards will complain about overriding the global post so if you're using the WordPress standards you'll need to disable it for the line like so:

```php
setup_postdata( $GLOBALS['post'] =& $post ); //phpcs:ignore
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution that works for me is:

1. `global $post;` before the loop
2. `setup_postdata($post);` inside the loop
3. `wp_reset_postdata();` after the loop

Take into account that the name of the variable must be `$post`