# How can I get next post id after current post id for custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, next-post-link, previous-post-link

Hello I am using WordPress custom post type. In this I need to get the post id of the next post which will be present in the custom post type.

The issue I am facing is that this post id will be dynamic So please let me know if there is a function which can help me to get the next post id of custom post type in WordPress.

Comment: Please check this link may be it will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6324421/getting-next-previous-post-id-using-current-post-id-in-wordpress

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the code inside a custom post type template, then the `get_next_post()` will get the next post for you. Then you can use the `->ID` and get it's ID. So:

```
$next_post = get_next_post();
$next_post_id = $next_post->ID;
```

If you need their link, simply use [`next_post_link()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_post_link) or [`previous_post_link()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_post_link).

These functions use the global post object, so you can manually set the global post data, use them and then reset the global object:

```
global $post; 
$post = get_post( $ID, OBJECT );
setup_postdata( $post );

// Use get_next_post();

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Code grabbed from an answer [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/53482/94498).